# Onclick function with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to design a bus seat arrangement with CSS and I completed the hover section with CSS but next part is to **select the seat** on which after click there should be change in  the background image.
I am using different IDs for each seat. Using the following code

```
.myClass {
    background:url('images/transparent-backgro-seatlayout.gif') 0 -60px;
}

document.getElementById("w1").className += " myClass";
```

but this is not working. As I don't know much about the java script, I am unable to solve my problem. Kindly help.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working` ?

Comment: Try [jQuery](http://jquery.com). With it you would write `$('#w1').click(function() { this.addClass('myClass'); });`

Comment: would be better if you post a sample of your HTML markup... without knowledge of what the element w1 is (span/div/some other html element) it would be a bit difficult to answer..also are you sure that the click event is firing properly in the first place?

Comment: I was expecting the result but I am not getting result.

Comment: I am using the div ID name as w1.

Comment: Without your html we're guessing. We need your help in order to help you. Consider posting a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net), or at least enough code we can reproduce your problem. By 'enough code' I mean [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery, this could be as easy as:

```
$("#w1").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('myClass');
});
```

Note that, by using $(this) you automatically refer to the element that was clicked.  This is handy as you mention there are many clickable seats, each with a unique id. Instead of manually creating an event handler for each clickable seat ("w1", "w2", etc.) it's simpler to use a selector which matches any of the seats. Assume all the seats are inside a tag with id "seats" and that each seat is represented with an "a" tag:

```
$("#seats a").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('myClass');
});
```

So your markup would be something like this:

```
<div id="seats">
  <a id="w1">seat 1</a>
  <a id="w2">seat 2</a>
  ....
</div>
```

Furthermore, if you wanted the user to be able to click the seat again to unselect it, use toggleClass instead of addClass:

```
$("#seats a").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('myClass');
});
```

Note that you don't have to use jquery to implement all of this. You could do it in raw javascript or you could use a different javascript framework. But if you have the choice, jquery makes coding this up a lot easier.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and used 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#w1").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('myClass');
});
$("#seats a").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('myClass');
})
$("#seats a").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('myClass');
});
 });
</script>`
 but could not get the result as I don't have jQuery knowledge.

Comment: Try this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" > $(document).ready(function() { $("#seats a").click(function() { $(this).toggleClass('myClass'); }); }); </script>` 1) You only need to load jquery once (looked like you were loading 2 copies of it). 2) You only need to add one click function (otherwise they risk cancelling each other out, specifically the last two).  3) Post a full example of the entire markup for more feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the use of [jQuery which allows easily this kind of thing](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/). In your case you would have

```
 $("#w1").addClass("myClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeImage(this){
   var el;
   el.classname = 'updatedImgClass';
}
```

Trigger the above function when we click on a particular seat by passing it's object